# Guide to debugging JS in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser

Can anyone suggest a guide, or tutorial that will explain how to debug JS in Chrome browser? I've seen people setting breakpoints and that sort of thing but I don't understand what they're doing.

Any tips around how/what to do when debugging in browser would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Thanks Chad. Does this explain how and why people use breakpoints? I've briefly scanned through it before and I've seen it points out what everything is (most of which I know already), but it doesn't tell me why I should use these things.

I may not be making sense here, but a good guide with examples of debugging code with breakpoints etc is what I'm looking for. That way I can get an understanding of WHY we do these things.

Answer (score 0):

In your function add "debbug;" and the console will be activated automatically when you reload your page. After that, look at the right side [image: debug console]

watch expressions block, you can add your variables. 
On the left side, you can add breakpoints.

Check the [google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) if you want to understand all the options.